# Delete multiple vertices from a graph based on list of node names

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to remove vertices from a graph based on a csv file containing the list of vertices which are to be removed.  I thought I could simply import this csv define the list as a variable and then add this to the delete.vertices argument.  However when I've checked the output of this the vertices I have specified to be removed are still in the network.  The correct number of vertices are in the new graph - however it's not deleting the vertices I need it to.  The code I have is below any help with this will be much appreciated.

```
data<-read.csv(file ="10percent.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
bet10<-data$vertex_removed
g_l10bet<-delete.vertices(g_L, v=bet10)
summary(g_l10bet)
cluster3<-clusters(g_l10bet)
V(g_l10bet)$ClusterID<-cluster3$membership
g_l10betnodes<-get.data.frame(g_l10bet, what = 'vertices')
write.csv(g_l10betnodes, file = "10percentremoved.csv")
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data? Otherwise it's hard to know what might be going on

Comment: If you are using the current version of igraph, you should use `delete_vertices` not `delete.vertices`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following line instead of line 3:

```
g_l10bet<-delete.vertices(g_L, bet10)
```